# Send post through two files

Tags: php, post

I'm making a login system in PHP. I have three files, **login.php**, **check.php** and **login_success.php**.

In the login.php I have the login form where you enter a username and password then hit a button which will send the data to **check.php** with **$_POST** to see if the login matches with the database. If it does, it will continue on to **login_success.php** where the user is actually logged in and will see the content of the webpage.

Now to my problem/question: I want to be able to use the variables that I posted to **check.php** from **login.php** in the **login_success.php**.

Is there a way I can keep posting the data through one file to a third?

I have tried using **include = 'check.php';** but that didn't work as nothing had been sent to that file so the variables were empty.

Hopefully someone knows a way, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just do the check inside `login.php`? Also, `include 'check.php';` should just work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want that Post data from login page to the login_success.php page then you must store that post data to the [`$_SESSION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) variable then only you will get it on the login success page.